# Cordova project build in Visula studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 to build .appx with emulator for apache cordova project. Whenever I import and build in visual studio emulator it is always showing the following error:

The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Vibration.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='debug'
Platform='x86'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying
to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a
non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this
project.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share your project with me? Also, do you have the latest version of Visual Studio installed (Update 3?) and what version of Cordova are you targeting?

Comment: I am using windows 10 64bit, visual studio 2015 and cordova 6.1.1

Comment: Can you provide me with a repro?

Comment: repro means..can you please tell what you need

Comment: I need a project that I can load into Visual Studio that has the problem so I can debug it and tell you why it's not working.

Comment: have you any idea above posted error...

Comment: Not without a repro, no.

Comment: ok, I will provide the project.Please wait for some time